# Changing Urls on ASP.NET form with Master pages

Tags: .net, asp.net, proxy, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

We've had a requirement from a client to move a site that is running on it's own domain to a subfolder of another app.

I've acheived this using ISAPI rewrite proxying.

However, there is one form that does a post back in the site. The generated url for the action from ASP.NET is **"/sign-up.aspx?"**. This sends the postback to the root of the site.

I want to change this to **"sign-up.aspx?"** (no leading slash). This would be fine if I wasn't using Master pages as I could get a reference to the form and change it's action (this is .NET 3.5 SP1). I've tried to use the following code in my control to get a reference to the form but it doesn't seem to do anything. It finds the form but the action is not set to the value.

```
        HtmlForm form = ControlLocator.FindControl<HtmlForm>(Page.Master.Master, "form1");
        form.Action = "sign-up.aspx?";
```

This is in Page_Load and ControlLocator.FindControl is a port of this http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5127.aspx

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out that it was umbraco's Form.browser that was rewriting the post back url after I had changed it. (Apologies for not mentioning the use of umbraco in my original question).

Answer (score 4):

Good to solve your problem. 
But for whom that wants to change the action URL of aspnetform, use this simple code in the Page_Load event (even they have a master page).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form.Action = "URL Goes Here";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried doing it in page_prerender?

It could be that all the master content merging has not yet been done in page_load. Assuming HtmlForm is the correct type and that the form is actually called 'form1' - which I'm sure is correct.

Comment: I did try doing it in prerender before page_load, no joy. There is no null reference so the form is definitely being found. Thanks for the answer anyway! :) Maybe I need to do it later in the lifecycle?

Comment: Just checking - pre-render should happen way after Page_Load- it's one of the last stages before the page is dumped.  Did you mean Pre_Init?

Could even try it in the start of Render; although it's possible that Asp.Net is simply ignoring any value you give it.  What's the value of Form.Action before you try and set it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button on the signup form you could use the [`postBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) attribute of it to redirect the postback to a different URL.

```
<asp:button id="SignUpBtn" 
            runat="server"
            postbackurl="sign-up.aspx" 
            value="Sign Up" />
```

You can find more information on this under ["Cross-page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).